# Immunity Debugger showing path instead of argv[1]

Tags: immunity-debugger

I'm trying to learn Buffer Overflow
Here is the vulnerable code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char buffer[64];

    if(argc < 2){
        printf("The number of argument is incorrect\n");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(buffer, argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to run the code in Immunity Debugger, I don't see AAAAAAA in the source in the stack pane I see the path to my test.exe. Later, I don't see 0x41s ....obviously

What is happening ?

[image]

Comment: argv[0] is the path to the executable AAAAAA is argument andtherfor it is argv[1] look at your code you are copying wrong  argument

Comment: @blabb How di you spot that so quickly. Thank you. That's obviously the issue

Comment: @blabb Go ahead and make that into an answer; comments are not a place to answer.

Comment: @blabb I don't mid accepting your answer instead of Igor's since you were the one actualy helping me solving the issue. It's up to you

Comment: @leila Thanks let it be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the program’s argument, you need to check `argv[1]` instead of `argv[0]`. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function):

> The parameters of the two-parameter form of the main function allow
> arbitrary multibyte character strings to be passed from the execution
> environment (these are typically known as command line arguments), the
> pointers `argv[1].. argv[argc-1]` point at the first characters in each
> of these strings. `argv[0]` is the pointer to the initial character of a
> null-terminated multibyte string that represents the name used to
> invoke the program itself (or an empty string "" if this is not
> supported by the execution environment).